# I wanted to execute a nested loop using foreach controller in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, web-api-testing

I have 2 get api's to get all the folders present, one on onprem and other on cloud. So I have used the json extractor and have extracted the folder id's and titles for both(folderid, fold_title, cld_folderid, cld_fold_title) , now I have to pass this folder id in another get api for both onprem and cloud so I could get the contents present in the folders and then compare to check if contents are same.

So I have used the foreach controller each for onprem and cloud get api to get contents in each folder and have nested them, cloud forach controller is inside onprem for each controller

The onprem foreach parameters are something like this:

input variable: folderid   (as extracted using json extractor)

start index : 0

end indes of loop : ${folderid_matchNr}

output varibale is folderidd

Then a get api is used to get the id and title(extractesd using json extractor) of all the content in that respective folder.

to get contents in a folder on onprem the url is something like:
[https://abc.onprem.com/${folderidd}](https://abc.onprem.com/$%7Bfolderidd%7D)

then inside this for each controller after the get api a foreach controller for cloud is inserted

for cloud same as above foreach controller details and output id is cld_folderidd

to get contents in a folder on cloud the url is something like:
[https://abc.cloud.com/${cld_folderidd}](https://abc.cloud.com/$%7Bcld_folderidd%7D)

inside this http request I have extracted the id and tittle so I could compare them using bean shell assertion.

[image]

While executing the script 1st folder on onprem is being checked against all the folders in cloud, the main problem is that I just wanted to compare the first folder of onprem with 1st folder of cloud and 2nd cloud of onprem with 2nd folder of cloud or only compare the folders with same title name.

So I have inserted a if controller in cloud for each controller before the get folder contents request. and the if controller condition is as such : ${__jexl3("${fold_title_ALL}"=="${cloud_fold_title_ALL}")}

here I can't check with folder id as it is not fixed in cloud a random number will be generated and assigned which will be different from onprem folder id

[image]

But still this isn't working, again one onprem folder is being compared with all folders on cloud please suggest me something so that I could check only one folder of onprem with one folder on cloud only!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use "nested" ForEach Controller, you need to use single ForEach Controller.

In order to get the relevant variable for cloud you can use [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) and [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) functions combination, i.e. something like:

```
${__V(cld_folderidd_${__intSum(${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx},1,)},)}
```

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Also be informed that [using Beanshell is some form of a performance anti-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), consider using [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and Groovy instead.